# OnBackPressed not called (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to do something on back pressed (on physical button), but a simple override is not being called. I am calling this from my activity which inherits AppCompatActivity :

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
```

and my breakpoint on base.OnBackPressed(); is never hit. Is it an issue in AppCompatActivity? I also tried overriding OnKeyUp and OnKeyDown, doesn't get called either.

Comment: Might sound silly, but can you try to output a debug message in the `OnBackPressed` method, to confirm its not being called? I only say this because I have occasionally run into issues with Visual Studio/Xamarin where my break points do not hit.

Comment: It doesn't sound silly at all. Turns out it's visual studio. I turned it off and on again and it's working now. Life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by restarting Visual Studio. Joy.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this and fixed it by

1. Clean project
2. Delete contents in  /obj and /bin folders